# Are there different meanings of "to drop something"?

Tags: verbs

I know that I can drop something: I accidentally make it fall to the ground.

But I want to know if I can use it in other ways like: I was trying hard to finish the task, but I dropped it. Meaning: I stopped trying to finish it.

If the second sentence is not correct, are there any other definitions of "to drop"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for dictionary definitions of the verb drop.  [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drop) or other sources would be a good place to start.

To make something fall to the ground is an example of the second definition:

> 2a(1): to fall (see FALL entry 1 sense 1a) unexpectedly or suddenly

To stop working on task is an example of the fourth definition:

> 4a: to cease to be of concern : LAPSE